# BIT.TRIP Runner 2 - alternate levels

Tags: runner2

I hope this kind of question will qualify for the purpose of this website. What is the purpose of alternate levels in BIT.TRIP. Runner 2 ? By alternate levels I mean those levels that stray from the "main path" on the world map and you have to "pay" some gold to play them.

It seems to me that the quantity of gold demanded is not so big and you can easily play them normally, also they are not more difficult (like the vault ones) or special in any other way.

**EDIT:** It looks to me that I was not so clear on my question. I was not talking about the alternate exits, I was talking about the levels on the WORLD MAP that are  "locked" and you have to pay gold to get to play them.

Comment: When updating your question, please try to actually update the information in the question to be more clear, rather than adding a big **EDIT:** block on the end.

Comment: @BillyMailman I think I explained pretty clearly what I had in mind, if other people thought of straying from a level's main direction, but i meant from the world map's road. If people would read carefully these situations wouldn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is to give you more incentive to collect the gold in the levels, rather than just trying to get through, if you aren't otherwise interested in high scores, perfect-level completion, etc. Even though the locked levels aren't that different, the prospect of having more levels to play is a nice reward for doing well in the other levels.